# Android Studio (0.8.1) cant use go to declaration/implementation

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-13

I cant seem to use go to declaration or implementation for any classes and methods that are outside of either the current class/file. It will work for classes that are from the android library but nothing that I created or that I import from another library. This is taking a huge toll on productivity... Anyone run into this? Have a solution? Ideas for a fix?

Also highlighting seems to be an issue as well, this might be related. It seems lighter then it used to be, like Annotations are not being highlighted. Maybe its a parser issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle to build your application, then make sure gradle project sync is not failing. If gradle project sync fails, then basic IDE functionality may not work properly e.g.  goto type declaration (ctrl+shift+b) and implementation (ctrl+alt+b or ctrl+click). Android studio also does a wonderful job of notifying you when something fails.